# fabric8 strange CLI feedback on win7

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8, minikube

Hi starting with fabric8 right now and getting strange outputs after installation.
System:
Win7/hyperV
minikube
gofabric8 0.4.133

on:
gofabric8 validate I got this:

```
C:\testp>gofabric8 validate
←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m▄▄←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;235m▄←[39m ←[00m
←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;235;38;5;235m█←[48;5;235;38;5;235m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;235;38;5;235m█←[49;39m ←
[00m
←[48;5;233;38;5;235m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;24m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[48;5;233;38;5;235m▄←[49;39m ←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;24m▄←[48;5;235;
38;5;24m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;235m█←[49;39m ←[00m
←[48;5;235;38;5;235m█←[48;5;24;38;5;24m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;24;38;5;24m█←[48;5;235;38;5;235m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;235;38;5;235m█←[49;39m ←[38;5;235m▀←[38;
5;235m▀▀▀▀▀←[38;5;233m▀←[39m ←[48;5;235;38;5;24m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;24m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;25m▄←[49;39m ←[00m
←[48;5;235;38;5;235m▄←[48;5;24;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;24;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;235m▄←[49;39m ←[48;5;67;
38;5;67m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;235;38;5;235m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[49;39m ←[00m
←[38;5;233m▄←[38;5;235m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;24m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;25m▄←[49;38;5;235m▄←[39m ←[48;5;67;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;
5;25m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[49;39m ←[00m
←[38;5;235m▀←[48;5;25;38;5;24m▄←[48;5;24;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;68m▄←[48;5;24;38;5;25m▄←[49;38;5;25m▄←[39m ←[38;5;235m▄←[38;5;235m▄←[38;5;17m▄←[39m ←[38;5;
25m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[38;5;235m▄←[39m ←[00m
←[38;5;23m▀←[48;5;110;38;5;60m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;254m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;233;38;5;25m▄←[49;38;5;235m▄←[38;5;24m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[48;5;60;38;5;25m▄
←[48;5;67;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;233;38;5;25m▄←[49;39m ←[38;5;233m▄←[48;5;17;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;3
8;5;25m▄←[48;5;24;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;24m▄←[49;38;5;233m▀←[39m←[00m
←[38;5;60m▀←[48;5;153;38;5;24m▄←[48;5;68;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;67;38;5;255m▄←[48;5;32;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;68;38;5;
110m▄←[48;5;68;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;110m▄←[38;5;110m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;24;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;233;38;5;25m▄←[49;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;24;38;5;25m▄←[4
8;5;25;38;5;25m█←[38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;24m▄←[49;38;5;17m▀←[39m ←[00m
←[38;5;233m▀←[38;5;24m▀←[48;5;25;38;5;235m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;153;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;67;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;252;38;5;255m▄←[48;5;254;38;5;231m▄←[48;5;254m▄←[48;
5;253;38;5;224m▄←[48;5;252;38;5;255m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;231m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;231m▄←[48;5;61;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[38;5;24m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;233m▄←[49;38;5;24m▀←[39m
←[00m
←[48;5;235;38;5;235m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;67;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;255;38;5;255m▄←[48;5;231;38;5;231m█←[48;5;255;38;5;216m▄←[48;5;223;38;5;2
09m▄←[48;5;223;38;5;223m▄←[48;5;231;38;5;231m█←[48;5;231;38;5;231m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;235m▄←[49;39m ←[00m
←[48;5;235;38;5;235m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;32;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;67;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;255;38;5;254m▄←[48;5;231;38;5;255m▄←[48;5;209;38;5;180m▄←[48;5;209;38;5;223
m▄←[48;5;224;38;5;173m▄←[48;5;231;38;5;255m▄←[48;5;231;38;5;255m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;235;38;5;235m▄←[49;39m ←[00m
←[48;5;25;38;5;235m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m█←[48;5;32m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;110;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;110m▄←[48;5;110m▄←[48;5;110m▄←[48;5;67m▄←[48;5;25;3
8;5;25m▄←[49;39m ←[00m
←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[49;38;5;235m▀←[38;5;235m▀←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;25m█←[48;5;25;38;5;25m▄←[49;3
9m ←[00m
←[38;5;188m▄←[48;5;242;38;5;188m▄←[48;5;242;38;5;188m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;250m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;67;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;68m▄←[48;5;250;38;5;25m▄←[48;5;188
;38;5;188m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;110m▄←[48;5;68;38;5;32m▄←[48;5;25;38;5;67m▄←[48;5;250;38;5;68m▄←[48;5;188;38;5;251m▄←[48;5;247;38;5;237m▄←[49;39m ←[00m
←[38;5;237m▀←[38;5;242m▀←[38;5;242m▀←[38;5;247m▀←[38;5;188m▀←[38;5;251m▀←[38;5;188m▀←[38;5;188m▀←[38;5;188m▀←[38;5;188m▀←[38;5;188m▀←[38;5;188m▀←[38;5;247m▀←[38;
5;237m▀←[39m ←[00m
Validating your Kubernetes installation at https://192.168.99.100:8443 in namespace default

Service account...............................................................?
Console.......................................................................?
Jenkinshift Service...........................................................?
PersistentVolumeClaims........................................................?
ConfigMaps....................................................................?

C:\testp>
```

(In blue console color)

Same outputs on
"gofabric8 volumes"
and some others...

Whats that? And how to get useful info?

Regards
Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a fabric8 logo. But seems like your shell cannot show ANSI colors so you see it outputted as plain text instead in black/white.

Comment: That makes sense :D thanks.... stupid windows.
It daring anyway trying to use fabric8 cluster on a win7 machine.